# "update" method with variable-length index in Scala

Tags: scala, shapeless, variadic-functions

I was writing code for something like an array with variable dimensions. What I do is to maintain a linear underlying collections and wrap it up with index access methods. Since the dimension of the data structure is not known, I write something like

```
def apply(i: Int*): Double = ...
```

And it works perfectly. However, I cannot do the same thing to update method and operators like +=, so I end up writing methods like

```
def set(v: Double, i: Int*) ...
def add(v: Double, i: Int*) ...
```

which is fine but not what I really want. I guess the problem about update may be fixed in two ways:

1. Change the order of arguments in update function, which makes it look weird.
2. Allow variable-length arguments not as the last one. I find this questions asked in a general setting and it can be solved by using currying functions, which does not apply here.

The problem about += seems more complicated and it even exists when the index is of fixed length. Maybe we can add an object that has += operator and use this(...) to get the object (so that this(...) += v will invoke some method as we expect), but that will conflict with the apply method.

If anyone has solution to any of the above questions or has a reason why we shouldn't be able to write code like this, please share your ideas! Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution I see right now is to have many different overloads of `update` for every dimension that you want to support. Say that you can determine that the maximum dimension that you'll ever use is 10, this means that you'll need 10 overloads. This might not seem very practical, but i can easily be abstracted away so it is very much practical actually:

```
trait MultiKeyUpdate[K, V] {
  def doUpdate( k: K* )( v: V )
  def update(k1: K, v: V) { doUpdate( k1 )( v ) }
  def update(k1: K, k2: K, v: V) { doUpdate( k1, k2 )( v ) }
  def update(k1: K, k2: K, k3: K, v: V) { doUpdate( k1, k2, k3 )( v ) }  
  // ... and so on, up until max dimension ...
}
```

Usage:

```
class C extends MultiKeyUpdate[Int, Double] {
  def apply(i: Int*): Double = {
    println("Returning element " + i.mkString("[",",","]"))
    123
  }
  def doUpdate( i: Int* )( v: Double ) {
    println("Updating element " + i.mkString("[",",","]") + " to value " + v)
  }
}
```

And some test in the REPL:

```
scala> val o = new C
o: C = C@12798c1
scala> o(1,2,3)
Returning element [1,2,3]
res3: Double = 123.0
scala> o(1,2,3) = 5.0
Updating element [1,2,3] to value 5.0
scala> o(1,2,3) += 7.0
Returning element [1,2,3]
Updating element [1,2,3] to value 130.0
```

Comment: I think this is the way scala developers implement many things in the system library, which looks kind of ugly to me... But I didn't know that they have the grammar sugar to automatically generate += operator when you already have apply and update, which is a useful thing to learn. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`update` is a fairly peculiar artefact in Scala because it is mainly syntactic sugar and doesn't correspond to any particular method signature. This means that we can be creative and give update an arity-polymorphic signature,

```
scala> class Indexed { def update[P <: Product](p: P) = p }
defined class Indexed

scala> val i = new Indexed
i: Indexed = Indexed@1ea0e836

scala> i(0) = 1.0
res0: (Int, Double) = (0,1.0)

scala> i(0, 1) = 1.0
res1: (Int, Int, Double) = (0,1,1.0)

scala> i(0, 1, 2) = 1.0
res2: (Int, Int, Int, Double) = (0,1,2,1.0)

scala> i(0, 1, 2, 3) = 1.0
res3: (Int, Int, Int, Int, Double) = (0,1,2,3,1.0)
```

As it stands, this leaves the types of the indices on the LHS and the type of the value on the RHS  completely unconstrained,

```
scala> i(23, true, 'c') = "foo"
res4: (Int, Boolean, Char, String) = (23,true,c,foo)
```

but we can fix that with some implicit evidence provided by the new [support for tuples](https://gist.github.com/milessabin/6081113) in [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT,

```
scala> import shapeless._
import shapeless._

scala> import syntax.tuple._
import syntax.tuple._

scala> class Indexed {
     |   def update[P <: Product, I](p: P)
     |     (implicit
     |       init:   TupleInit.Aux[P, I],
     |       toList: TupleToList[I, Int],
     |       last:   TupleLast.Aux[P, Double]) = (toList(init(p)), last(p))
     | }
defined class Indexed

scala> val i = new Indexed
i: Indexed = Indexed@76ab909a

scala> i(0) = 1.0
res10: (List[Int], Double) = (List(0),1.0)

scala> i(0, 1) = 2.0
res11: (List[Int], Double) = (List(0, 1),2.0)

scala> i(0, 1, 2) = 3.0
res12: (List[Int], Double) = (List(0, 1, 2),3.0)

scala> i(0, 1, 2, 3) = 4.0
res13: (List[Int], Double) = (List(0, 1, 2, 3),4.0)

scala> i(0, 1, 2) = "foo" // Doesn't compile
<console>:22: error: could not find implicit value for parameter
  last: shapeless.ops.tuple.TupleLast.Aux[(Int, Int, Int, String),Double]
              i(0, 1, 2) = "foo" // Doesn't compile
                         ^

scala> i(23, "foo", true) = 5.0 // Doesn't compile
<console>:22: error: could not find implicit value for parameter
  toList: shapeless.ops.tuple.TupleToList[I,Int]
              i(23, "foo", true) = 5.0 // Doesn't compile
                                 ^
```

Comment: this is really useful information, and a very practical use of shapeless.  Would you be able to add a short blog post about this discover?

Comment: I would ... watch this space.

Answer (score 1):

```
class SetMe {
  def set(i: Int*)(v: Double) { println("Set "+v+" with "+i.mkString(",")) }
}

scala> (new SetMe).set(4,7,19,3)(math.Pi)
Set 3.141592653589793 with 4,7,19,3
```

Can't do that trick with `update` itself, however.  Might be worth filing an enhancement request.